# xss javascript protection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, xss

So i am using the jQuery UI library to open new dialog windows, when the new dialog windows are opened I am passing some parameters like this

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/custompage.html?width=100&height=200&param1=abc&param2=http://www.anothersite.com&param3=custom3">open modal</a>
```

The site works fine and no issues at all, my custompage.html just picks up those values that were passed and they are being used on the page, something like this:

```
var a = customfunctionget(param1); var b = customfunctionget(param2)....
```

I just received a report that we are vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting attacks by replacing any of the params with something like this:

```
><script>alert(123)</script><param
```

Which I understand correctly what is supposed to happen but on any browser that I try to inject the script the alert is never displayed so the "script/injection" is not being processed, the custompage.html stops working as expected since we need the values to be entered correctly but there is nothing I can do on that respect.

Is there a magic pill that I am missing here? Most of the XSS information that I find does the same thing, try to inject an alert through a tag but other than me denying to display any content if the parameter is not well formed I dont know what else can be done.

Any recommendations, tutorials welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easiest things you can encode all `<`, `>`, and `&` characters with `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;`, respectively.  Whenever a browser sees a `<something>` it thinks its a dom element.  If you encode those characters, the browser will actually display them. This will foil people trying to execute `<script>badstuff</script>` on your site.

Note that people won't be able to do things like add `<b>` tags to things if you do this.

The above suggestion is a first step, but is by no means exhaustive.

I just found this, which seems like a [good guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: So if I encode everything per your suggestion and when some one replaces a parameter with a script `<script>bs</script>` there is still nothing I can do, meaning anyone can view source and get my anchor tag, replace one of the parameters and hit the page directly. I am not sure how that is "protecting" the page other than just break as it did before since the parameter is not formed correctly

Comment: also, wouln't the intruder be able to encode the scrip tag `%3Cscript%3Ebs%3C%2Fscript%3E` and the browser just ignore this "security".

Comment: helmut yes, which is why i said "The above suggestion is a first step, but is by no means exhaustive." in my answer.  Look at the link...

Answer (score 0):

There is encodeURIComponent() function in Javascripts to encode special characters to avoid inserting scripts